# In Beamer, command to increment the slide count?

Tags: beamer, overlays

Is there a way to increment the slide count in a *relative* way? I assume I could do `\setcounter{beamerpauses}{5}` if I knew I wanted it set to 5, but I'd like to be able to add something before it, without renumbering everything.

One workaround would be just put an uncover with nothing inside it: `\uncover<+>{}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\addtocounter{beamerpauses}{x}`, to increase the counter by `x`.

**Example-Code:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> 1
    \item<2-> 2
    \item<3-> 3
    \item<4-> 4
    \item<5-> 5
    \item<6-> 6
    \end{itemize}

    \addtocounter{beamerpauses}{2}
    \pause
    D (show with 4)

    \pause
    E (show with 5)

    \pause
    F (show with 6)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want more than one pause, you can add this number as optional argument to `\pause[<n>]`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    before pause

    \pause[5]

    after pauses
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, I guess I overlooked the most obvious option: just put `\pause`!